# VBA: Increase row number for my code

Tags: vba

Below is my vba code,

```
For x = 0 To EleXML.ChildNodes.Length - 1    
      Range("A10" & x) = EleXML.ChildNodes.Item(x).getAttribute("aa")
      Range("A10" & x) = EleXML.ChildNodes.Item(x).getAttribute("bb")
      Range("A10" & x) = EleXML.ChildNodes.Item(x).getAttribute("cc")
    Next x
```

My cell will begin from "A10", how can I auto increase it using "x" in my code? So,it should be "A11" in next loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about: `Range("A1" & str(x)) = ...`?

Comment: I got it...Range("A10" & x) = EleXML.ChildNodes.Item(x).getAttribute("aa")
      Range("A" activerow & x) = EleXML.ChildNodes.Item(x).getAttribute("bb")
      Range("B"  activerow & x) = EleXML.ChildNodes.Item(x).getAttribute("cc")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For x = 0 To EleXML.ChildNodes.Length - 1    
      Range("A10").offset(x,0) = EleXML.ChildNodes.Item(x).getAttribute("aa")
      Range("A10").offset(x,0) = EleXML.ChildNodes.Item(x).getAttribute("bb")
      Range("A10").offset(x,0) = EleXML.ChildNodes.Item(x).getAttribute("cc")
Next x
```

I almost always use `Offset` in these situations ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224911%28v=office.11%29.aspx)) because it is much, much, MUCH more clear than trying to manually create a string range.

It makes things much more clear when you are iterating and have something like

```
myRange.offset(rowOffset, colOffset)
```

than nearly all alternatives (such as the other answer or those posted in comments).

You could also look into using `Cells(row, col)` syntax.

Comment: enderland:Thanks for the answer. How can I align all the values to center??

Comment: `Range("A10").offset(x,0).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter` inside your for loop

Answer (score 1):

Very simple:

```
For x = 0 To EleXML.ChildNodes.Length - 1    
  Range("A" & (10 + x)) = EleXML.ChildNodes.Item(x).getAttribute("aa")
  Range("B" & (10 + x)) = EleXML.ChildNodes.Item(x).getAttribute("bb")
  Range("C" & (10 + x)) = EleXML.ChildNodes.Item(x).getAttribute("cc")
Next x
```

Comment: I would recommend against this as a long term plan. This sort of approach becomes really hard to read and immediately understand later (especially when things get more complicated) even though it works.

Comment: For larger project you may be right. I generally use a control variable to indicate the starting row etc. However, you can see that the person asking has absolutely no experience in programming, so the simpler the answer the better.

Comment: This answer is not simple ;)

Comment: I suppose, using offsets isn't incredibly difficult, but then it's still one less thing to worry about if you don't understand the principles of programming. Afterall, it's a matter of preference!